# Django Select Widget Groups template

Tags: django, forms, templates

I have the following models:

```
# Group for Key/Value pairs
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Group'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Groups'

# Key is the key/name for a Value
class Key(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Key'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Keys'

# Value is the value/content of a key
class Value(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.value


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Value'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Values'

class Key_Value(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    key = models.ForeignKey(Key)
    value = models.ForeignKey(Value)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s = %s' % (self.key.name, self.value.value)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Key/Value Paar'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Key/Value Paare'


Now I pass the form to the template:
def exampleview(request):
    key_value_form = Key_Value_Form(request.POST)
    return render_to_response(
            'edit.html', {
                'key_value_form': key_value_form,
                })
```

Now lets look at possible data

```
KEY/VALUE PARIRS:
key = TEST 1
value = TEST 1
group = TESTGROUP 1

key = TEST 2
value = TEST 2
group = TESTGROUP 2
```

Now I changed the default widgets for the Key/Value Table entries to select widgets.

Here's what I want to do:

```
SELECT GROUP [+] [-]
   --> [Now choose Key/Value pair belonging to group] [+] [-]
```

at the start you always get two selects one for the group and one for the key/value pair.
if you press the + at the GROUP a new group select button should appear along with a KEY/Value Pair select, if you press the + at the Key/Value select a new key/value select box should appear.

I have two problems:

ONE: I don't know how the check in the template should look like and
TWO: How I can implement those + - Buttons

**Any Help is appreciated**. It would be cool if this would be possible without javascript but I don't have very high hopes in that direction

Comment: What are those `Admin` classes in your models?

Comment: Not Relevant to my question and they have been removed already

Comment: It's possible without javascript using simply CSS, but then you would have to submit post actions back to django to rerender the form with a parameter on how many groups and/or key widgets it needs to display and save. Javascript is much cleaner solution though.

Comment: @digivampire, How, with javascript?

Comment: @digivampire, because I never used javascript before for anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the form on the fly. Suppose you had a definition of a group form built in a dictionary from a view in your view handler (containing group model foreign keys and number of actual keys in them):

```
# note that the dictionary d shown here is just an example
# yours should have actual group foreign keys based on Group model
d = { 'first' : 5,  'second' : 3, 'third' : 2 }

def make_groupkeys_form(descriptor):
    groups = { 'select': '', 'keypairs' : [] }
    fields = { 'groups' : groups }

    for group, numkeys in descriptor.values():
        groupchoices = # find out what choices you need to offer for group widget
        groups['select'] = forms.SelectField(choices=groupchoices)
        for i in range(numkeys):
             keyvalchoices = # find out what choices you need to offer for keyval widget per group
             groups['keypairs'].append(forms.SelectField(choices=keyvalchoices))

    # now you have enough SelectFields for all your groups and keyval pairs
    return type('Key_Value_Form', (forms.BaseForm,), { 'base_fields': fields })

# from view handler
def exampleview(request):
    # determine from request how many groups you want and how many keyval widgets per group, for example here I will use the above predefined d

    key_value_form = make_groupkeys_form(d)
    return render_to_response(
            'edit.html', {
                'key_value_form': key_value_form,
                })
```

Note that you can (and should) rewrite a class `Key_Value_Form` to inherit from forms.BaseForm and put the make_groupkeys_form(descriptor) code in its `__init__(request, descriptor)` member. You will also need to do write your own `is_valid()` to enumerate through select fields and make sure the choices are correct when the user submits the form and override `clean()` to attempt to validate individual user's choices.

Finally, consider going through this [dynamic forms read](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/). It will guide you step by step in how to create dynamic forms in django.